# Button isn't showing below ListView in TabLayout

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm using Android Studio v3.1.2. I have a pair of activities with a ListView and a button. The button should alignParentBottom no matter how many items are in the ListView.

On my MainActivity, the ListView and Button render perfectly on a RelativeLayout. I can add lots of items to the ListView and the button stays put.

My JournalTabFragment, on the other hand, is a Fragment using a RelativeLayout in a TabLayout. The Fragment is created in code by the PetDetailTabbedActivity. The Fragment's layout is a modified version of the MainActivity layout, but the button doesn't show up, even when the ListView contains no data. I've tried using a LinearLayout with weights with limited success -- the button appears, but it floats below the listview content and moves down as data is added to the ListView. Then it gets scrunched vertically when there are several rows in the ListView.

Here's the most recent layout I've tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp"
        >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/journallistview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addentrybtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:text="@string/addentrybtn" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Because it's so similar to the layout on MainActivity, it *seems* like it should work, so I can't help but think the TabLayout has something to do with it.

What am I missing?! How do I get the button to stick to the bottom of the Activity layout without getting squashed? TIA for the help. Here's the Java for the parent activity that creates the Fragments.

```
public class PetDetailTabbedActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DeleteConfirmDialog.DeleteConfirmDialogListener {

    private SectionsPageAdapter mSectionsPageAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    DatabaseHelper myDB;
    Integer iPetID = 0;
    private int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    JournalTabFragment journalFrag;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pet_detail_tabbed_activity);

        myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        //load the toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        //let's give it a back button in the title bar
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        assert getSupportActionBar() != null;

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(bundle != null) {
            //get the pet ID from the extras
            iPetID = bundle.getInt("PetID");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if(iPetID > 0) {
            String sPetName = myDB.getPetNameByID(iPetID);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(sPetName);
        }
        mSectionsPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.container);
        setupViewPager(mViewPager);

        TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter((getSupportFragmentManager()));

        String sStatus = myDB.getPetStatusByPetID(iPetID);

        journalFrag = new JournalTabFragment();
        Bundle jbundle = new Bundle();
        jbundle.putInt("PetID", iPetID);
        journalFrag.setArguments(jbundle);

        PetDetailTabFragment petFrag = new PetDetailTabFragment();
        Bundle gbundle = new Bundle();
        gbundle.putInt("PetID", iPetID);
        petFrag.setArguments(gbundle);

        //add the tabs
        adapter.addFragment(journalFrag, "Journal");
        adapter.addFragment(petFrag,"Details");

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.detailsmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.home:
                goHome();
                return true;
            case R.id.edit:
                openEditActivity();
                return true;
            case R.id.delete:
                deletePet();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }

    private void goHome() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(PetDetailTabbedActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void openEditActivity() {
        Intent editIntent;
        editIntent = new Intent(PetDetailTabbedActivity.this, EditPetActivity.class);
        editIntent.putExtra("PetID", iPetID);
        startActivityForResult(editIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }


    private void deletePet() {

        //bundle up the iEntryID for the dialog to pass back;
        //    otherwise it's null when the dlg closes
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("ItemID", iPetID);

        DeleteConfirmDialog dlg = new DeleteConfirmDialog();
        dlg.setArguments(args);
        dlg.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Confirm Delete Dialog");
    }

    @Override
    public void applyValue(int itemid) {

        //the deletePet method in the db helper class also deletes journal entries for this pet
        Integer iPetID = (Integer)itemid;
        boolean bSuccess = myDB.deletePet(iPetID);
        if (bSuccess == true) {
            displayToastShort("Successfully deleted");
            Intent gobacktoprevactivity = new Intent();
            setResult(RESULT_OK,gobacktoprevactivity);
            finish();
        }
        else
            displayToastLong("Cannot delete the pet");
    }

    public void displayToastLong(String message) {
        StyleableToast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG, R.style.AccentToast).show();
    }
    public void displayToastShort(String message) {
        StyleableToast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, R.style.AccentToast).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                recreate();
                journalFrag.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

[image: Screenshot of ListView but no button on the bottom]

UPDATE: Here's the layout that partially works (it shows the button). As you can see, it floats up off the bottom when there are few rows in the ListView and gets pushed down when there are several rows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/journallistview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addentrybtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/addentrybtn" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Try insert the button in the LinearLayout!

Comment: Yes, I've tried using a LinearLayout with weights with limited success -- the button appears, but it floats below the listview content and moves down as data is added to the ListView.

Comment: I have updated my answer below to reflect a setup where my original earlier suggestion works. Below its the JournalFragment layout. You have not shared your Activity layout so my guess is, it has something to do with that because the solution i posted previously works as per below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

After re-reading your problem I setup a project that uses an Activity with two Fragments just as you describe above.

Here is the JournalFragment Layout (Layout suggested in previous answer):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/addentrybtn"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp"
        >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/journallistview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addentrybtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:text="ADD ENTRY" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

with code for JournalFragment:

```
public class JournalFragment extends Fragment {


  public static JournalFragment newInstance(){
    return new JournalFragment();
  }

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_journal, container, false);
  }


  @Override
  public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    ListView listView = view.findViewById(R.id.journallistview);
    final ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(view.getContext(),  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getItems(100));
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
  }


  private String []  getItems(int count){
    String [] items = new String[count];
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
      items[i] = "Item "+ i;
    }
    return items;
  }
}
```

The DetailFragment is useless here (stubbed for display purposes) but for completeness i will include it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Detail Fragment!"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

code for DetailFragment (again for completeness):

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

  public static DetailFragment newInsance(){
    return new DetailFragment();
  }

  @Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);
  }
}
```

Here is the Activity layout (barebones RelativeLayout, Toolbar, TabLayout, and ViewPager):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/journalToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/journalToolbar"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        app:tabTextColor="#fff"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The Activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.journalToolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
  }


  private final class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
      super(fm);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
      return position == 0 ? getString(R.string.journal) : getString(R.string.details);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

      if(position == 0){
        return JournalFragment.newInstance();
      }else{
        return DetailFragment.newInsance();
      }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return 2;
    }
  }
}
```

The Result:
[image: Activity with Tabs and docked button]

Good Luck and Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, it had no effect. The button still doesn't appear.

Comment: Thanks so much for the update. This is looking very promising so far! Using your code, I see the button sticking to the bottom, and even if I fill the list view with only a few items, the button stays. I'll populate with actual data and check back in to let you know how I fare. :)

Comment: @rottlover you are welcome hopefully this helped solve your problem

Comment: Update: Everything works great! Marking this as my solution. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Write this inside your LinearLayout tag

```
android:layout_above="@+id/addentrybtn"
```

It will place your listview above the button which is at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, it had the effect of putting the ListView's data at the bottom of the activity and still no button appeared.